# What does None=1 refer in the following enum class?

Tags: c#, enums

I have noticed the following enum declaration while browsing some sample code. What does None=1 mean ?

```
public enum ButtonActions
{
    None = 1,        
    Clear,
    Insert,       
    Delete,
    Cancel,
    Close
}
```

Comment: A really bad enum, cause zero is undefined but can be created easily: `var invalid = default(ButtonActions);`

Comment: @Oliver It's not undefined, it merely doesn't have a name. In general, you already cannot assume anything about an enum's value, there is nothing preventing an `enum E { A, B, C }` from holding a value of 3.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It marks the value of `None`, which then all following values implicitly count upward from then on:

`Clear` will be 2 
`Insert` will be 3 
...

Normally, without any marker, `enum`s default to beginning at 0 and counting upward.

Side note: you can always specify a new "starting" value at any time, and the ordering restarts. For example:

```
public enum ButtonActions
{
    None = 1,        
    Clear,
    Insert,       
    Delete = 7,
    Cancel,
    Close
}
```

Now, it will be:

`None` : 1 
`Clear` : 2 
`Insert` : 3 
`Delete` : 7 
`Cancel` : 8 
`Close` : 9

In C#, `enum`s are strongly typed sets of named constants for **underlying integral types**. Even though they are their own types with their own methods, underneath the curtains it's all just numbers. When you compare one `enum` to another, it is more or less an integral comparison.

They are designed in such a way that it is not *absolutely necessary* to know or care about the actual number the named constants represent - this is in fact why they exist at all, so that you aren't writing `3` and `5` in your code everywhere. But that doesn't change the fact that **each named constant maps to a number, ultimately**, and so in many cases it is nice to have this degree of control over precisely *what* numbers they each represent.

Comment: Could you please explain why do we use those numbers..? because when using enums i usually compare the value with enum value.

Comment: @Sravan because sometimes the value that an enum represents is important - e.g. network protocols.

Answer (score 5):

From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138362.aspx);

> By default the underlying type of each element in the enum is **int**.
>
> The following are advantages of using an enum instead of a numeric
>   type:
>
> - You clearly specify for client code which values are valid for the variable.
> - In Visual Studio, IntelliSense lists the defined values.
>
> When you do not specify values for the elements in the enumerator
>   list, the values are automatically incremented by **1**. When you create an enum, select the most logical default value and give it a value of zero. That will cause all enums to have that default value if they are not explicitly assigned a value when they are created.

I believe the one of the most important part is why we using these values is **bit flags**. Using with [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.flagsattribute.aspx) you can use bitwise operations like **AND**, **OR**, **NOT** and **XOR** on your enum elements. Example of [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138362.aspx) page;

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0x0,
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
class MyClass
{
    Days2 weekends = Days2.Sunday | Days2.Saturday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are making `enum` they are represented as `int` starting from 0.

I'm not absolutely sure but maybe in this way the enumeration will start from 1.
You can try it by simply "if (`None == 1`)" and check return value.

As I said I'm not 100% sure, but you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that you can refer to that using

```
ButtonActions bt = ButtonActions.None;
```

OR

```
ButtonActions bt = (ButtonActions)1;
```

That is used to force the enumeration to start counting from 1 instead of 0.